# Does leaflet 1.2.0 have a replacement for reuseTiles

Tags: leaflet

In leaflet version 0.7.3, we set reuseTitles to true as show below:

var osm = L.tileLayer(gOsmUrl, { minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 19, attribution: osmAttrib, noWrap: true, reuseTiles: true });

Is there an equivalent way to do that in 1.2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The founder of Leaflet delete that option because it does not any effect

- Leaflet/issues/2567#issuecomment-38528787

> "@danzel "reuse" option was ditched because it doesn't really do
>   much."

- Leaflet/issues/3102#issuecomment-67953928

> "@Bravoz hmm, it looks like the reuseTiles option is causing
>   uncontrolled memory growth — when I remove it, it works much better.
>   Can you check this? This option was removed in the master branch btw
>   because I was doubtful of its effectiveness."

- Leaflet/issues/4039

> "@yohanboniface I referred to retaining tiles on the current zoom when
>   panning. I removed it when reworking the logic meaning to add it back
>   some time later, but never did. I'm not sure we should though — or
>   maybe we should but in a limited form (e.g. retain tiles only within X
>   pixels from the current screen). Retaining already loaded tiles is
>   different from #3551 though (which is loading yet unseen tiles)."

This option was remove on the following commit - https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/5e6f95dc9ce86fcd2f191f0abbe7a8ea0d4f888f#diff-41e07cc2f66148151bde6b9e17c7f183 and never has been added back.

There are more info - https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/search?p=2&q=reuseTiles&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

So it's no equivalent in leaflet greater then 1.0.0